# How to fix font drawing over itself

Tags: c#, monogame

So I am having an issue in Microsoft Visual Studios, I am using Monogame as well, with the score drawing over itself, ie the 0 mixes with the 5 and so on.
Was wondering if anyone could have an answer to solve this problem.
my code is listed below.

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here

        timer += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds; // Increment the timer by the elapsed game time.

        if (timer >= 10000) // Check to see if ten seconds has passed.
        {
            score += 5; // Increment the score by 5.
            timer -= 10000; // Reset the timer.
        }

        spriteBatch.Begin();

        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Score: " + score, new Vector2(50, 70), Color.DarkRed);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Time Elapsed", new Vector2(50, 50), Color.GhostWhite);

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could clear the screen between draws, put this line at the beginning;

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);   // Clear screen
    ....
```

Comment: A little bit of information that a draw is called every frame. If you don't clear the field, it will draw over it's previous frame. In XNA game design, all images have to be drawn and redrawn every frame.